# Get Simple products price of configurable products of current category in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, simple-product

I am trying to get all simple products of configurable products and display it according to categories. I am using :

```
<?php 
    $attributes = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionFactory');
    $attributes = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    foreach ($collection as $product){
            echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().' - Price  =  '.$product->getPrice(). '<br>';
        }
?>`
```

When i am using this code , I am getting all the simple products assigned to configurable product. But I have to display the current category' Product which are assigned to configurable products. Can anybody please help me.

Comment: Then you can get current category and load the configurable products assigned to that category.

Comment: `<?php
        $parentId = $category->getParentId();

        $currentname = $category->getName(); 

        $parentIds = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId());

if(count($parentIds)>0 && $_product->getTypeId() == "simple")
        {
            /*?><script>console.log('<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>')</script><?php */
        }
    else {
/* Here i ma putting my code */
}` 

But again getting all products...